# Turn a database column into a string adding characters dynamicaly

Tags: python

i am fetching from my db values :

```
for value in values:
    print(value)
```

A
B
C

and i would like to dynamically create a string variable `text` which will hold the following:

```
text = 'value = A | value = B | value = c'
```

Comment: Are you not capturing the key too? You're sure you want `'value'` to be the key for each value?

Comment: yes this is the text i want to produce

Comment: It's extremely unclear to me what you're asking. Can you be more specific, and far more detailed? Have you even tried anything? What database are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this in a loop.

```
text = ''
for idx, value in enumerate(values):
    if idx != 0:
        text += ' | '
    text += ('value = ' + value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
text = ''
for value in values:
    text += 'value = {} | '.format(value)
text.rstrip('| ')
```